# Force Close in alarm while porting

Tags: android, sony-xperia, smali

i was trying to port SemcClock.apk by decompiling with apktool (From api 19 to api 18)But experiencing some fc.
the alarm sets properly but at the alarm time it force closes.

Logcat

```
09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Landroid/content/Context;.startService
09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): at com.sonyericsson.alarm.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:146)
09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2488)
09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:150)
09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-08 00:37:13.064 E/ActivityManager(1025): ANR in com.sonyericsson.organizer
09-08 00:37:13.064 E/ActivityManager(1025): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=com.sonyericsson.alarm.ALARM_ALERT flg=0x10000014 cmp=com.sonyericsson.organizer/com.sonyericsson.alarm.AlarmReceiver (has extras) }
```

AlarmReceiver.smali

```
.class public Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/AlarmReceiver;
.super Landroid/content/BroadcastReceiver;
.source "AlarmReceiver.java"


# static fields
.field private static final BACKUP_COMPLETE_APPLICATION:Ljava/lang/String; =       "com.sonyericsson.vendor.backuprestore.intent.PACKAGE_NAME"

.field private static final BACKUP_COMPLETE_INTENT:Ljava/lang/String; = "com.sonyericsson.vendor.backuprestore.intent.ACTION_RESTORE_APP_COMPLETE"

.field private static final PACKAGE_NAME:Ljava/lang/String; = "com.sonyericsson.organizer"

.field private static final STALE_WINDOW:I = 0x1b7740


# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
.locals 0

.prologue
.line 39
invoke-direct {p0}, Landroid/content/BroadcastReceiver;-><init>()V

return-void
.end method

 .method private getNotificationManager(Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/app/NotificationManager;
.locals 1
.param p1, "context"    # Landroid/content/Context;

.prologue
.line 190
const-string v0, "notification"

invoke-virtual {p1, v0}, Landroid/content/Context;->getSystemService(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

move-result-object v0

check-cast v0, Landroid/app/NotificationManager;

return-object v0
.end method

.method private updateNotification(Landroid/content/Context;Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;I)V
.locals 12
.param p1, "context"    # Landroid/content/Context;
.param p2, "alarm"    # Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;
.param p3, "timeout"    # I

.prologue
const/4 v11, 0x0

const/4 v10, 0x1

.line 194
invoke-direct {p0, p1}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/AlarmReceiver;->getNotificationManager(Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/app/NotificationManager;

move-result-object v4

.line 196
.local v4, "nm":Landroid/app/NotificationManager;
if-nez p2, :cond_0

.line 223
:goto_0
return-void

.line 204
:cond_0
new-instance v5, Landroid/content/Intent;

const-class v6, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/AlarmAlertFullScreen;

invoke-direct {v5, p1, v6}, Landroid/content/Intent;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/Class;)V

.line 205
.local v5, "viewAlarm":Landroid/content/Intent;
const-string v6, "intent.extra.alarm"

invoke-virtual {v5, v6, p2}, Landroid/content/Intent;->putExtra(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/Parcelable;)Landroid/content/Intent;

.line 206
iget v6, p2, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->id:I

invoke-static {p1, v6, v5, v11}, Landroid/app/PendingIntent;->getActivity(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/content/Intent;I)Landroid/app/PendingIntent;

move-result-object v1

.line 210
.local v1, "intent":Landroid/app/PendingIntent;
invoke-virtual {p2, p1}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->getLabelOrDefault(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v2

.line 211
.local v2, "label":Ljava/lang/String;
new-instance v0, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

invoke-direct {v0, p1}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V

.line 212
.local v0, "builder":Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;
const v6, 0x7f020050

invoke-virtual {v0, v6}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setSmallIcon(I)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v6

invoke-virtual {v6, v2}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setTicker(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v6

iget-wide v7, p2, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->time:J

invoke-virtual {v6, v7, v8}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setWhen(J)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v6

invoke-virtual {v6, v2}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setContentTitle(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v6

const v7, 0x7f0b0013

new-array v8, v10, [Ljava/lang/Object;

invoke-static {p3}, Ljava/lang/Integer;->valueOf(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;

move-result-object v9

aput-object v9, v8, v11

invoke-virtual {p1, v7, v8}, Landroid/content/Context;->getString(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v7

invoke-virtual {v6, v7}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setContentText(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v6

invoke-virtual {v6, v1}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setContentIntent(Landroid/app/PendingIntent;)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v6

invoke-virtual {v6, v10}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setOngoing(Z)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v6

invoke-virtual {v6, v10}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setLocalOnly(Z)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

.line 216
invoke-virtual {v0}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->build()Landroid/app/Notification;

move-result-object v3

.line 221
.local v3, "n":Landroid/app/Notification;
iget v6, p2, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->id:I

invoke-virtual {v4, v6}, Landroid/app/NotificationManager;->cancel(I)V

.line 222
iget v6, p2, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->id:I

invoke-virtual {v4, v6, v3}, Landroid/app/NotificationManager;->notify(ILandroid/app/Notification;)V

goto :goto_0
.end method


# virtual methods
.method public onReceive(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/content/Intent;)V
.locals 29
.param p1, "context"    # Landroid/content/Context;
.param p2, "intent"    # Landroid/content/Intent;

.prologue
.line 55
new-instance v3, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

invoke-direct {v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V

const-string v4, "action: "

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v3

invoke-virtual/range {p2 .. p2}, Landroid/content/Intent;->getAction()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v4

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v3

invoke-virtual {v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v3

invoke-static {v3}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Log;->v(Ljava/lang/String;)V

.line 57
const-string v3, "alarm_killed"

invoke-virtual/range {p2 .. p2}, Landroid/content/Intent;->getAction()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v4

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Ljava/lang/String;->equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

move-result v3

if-eqz v3, :cond_1

.line 59
invoke-static/range {p1 .. p1}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/IlluminationEffects;->stopEffects(Landroid/content/Context;)V

.line 62
:try_start_0
const-string v3, "intent.extra.alarm"

move-object/from16 v0, p2

invoke-virtual {v0, v3}, Landroid/content/Intent;->getParcelableExtra(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/Parcelable;

move-result-object v25

.line 63
.local v25, "parcel":Landroid/os/Parcelable;
check-cast v25, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;

.end local v25    # "parcel":Landroid/os/Parcelable;
const-string v3, "alarm_killed_timeout"

const/4 v4, -0x1

move-object/from16 v0, p2

invoke-virtual {v0, v3, v4}, Landroid/content/Intent;->getIntExtra(Ljava/lang/String;I)I

move-result v3

move-object/from16 v0, p0

move-object/from16 v1, p1

move-object/from16 v2, v25

invoke-direct {v0, v1, v2, v3}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/AlarmReceiver;->updateNotification(Landroid/content/Context;Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;I)V
:try_end_0
.catch Landroid/os/BadParcelableException; {:try_start_0 .. :try_end_0} :catch_0

.line 187
:cond_0
:goto_0
return-void

.line 65
:catch_0
move-exception v17

.line 66
.local v17, "e":Landroid/os/BadParcelableException;
invoke-virtual/range {v17 .. v17}, Ljava/lang/Throwable;->getMessage()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v3

invoke-static {v3}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Log;->e(Ljava/lang/String;)V

goto :goto_0

.line 69
.end local v17    # "e":Landroid/os/BadParcelableException;
:cond_1
const-string v3, "cancel_snooze"

invoke-virtual/range {p2 .. p2}, Landroid/content/Intent;->getAction()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v4

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Ljava/lang/String;->equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

move-result v3

if-eqz v3, :cond_2

.line 70
const/4 v3, -0x1

const-wide/16 v6, -0x1

move-object/from16 v0, p1

invoke-static {v0, v3, v6, v7}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarms;->saveSnoozeAlert(Landroid/content/Context;IJ)V

goto :goto_0

.line 72
:cond_2
const-string v3, "com.sonyericsson.vendor.backuprestore.intent.ACTION_RESTORE_APP_COMPLETE"

invoke-virtual/range {p2 .. p2}, Landroid/content/Intent;->getAction()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v4

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Ljava/lang/String;->equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

move-result v3

if-eqz v3, :cond_3

const-string v3, "com.sonyericsson.organizer"

invoke-virtual/range {p2 .. p2}, Landroid/content/Intent;->getExtras()Landroid/os/Bundle;

move-result-object v4

const-string v6, "com.sonyericsson.vendor.backuprestore.intent.PACKAGE_NAME"

invoke-virtual {v4, v6}, Landroid/os/Bundle;->get(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

move-result-object v4

invoke-virtual {v4}, Ljava/lang/Object;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v4

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Ljava/lang/String;->equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

move-result v3

if-eqz v3, :cond_3

.line 75
const/4 v3, -0x1

const-wide/16 v6, -0x1

move-object/from16 v0, p1

invoke-static {v0, v3, v6, v7}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarms;->saveSnoozeAlert(Landroid/content/Context;IJ)V

.line 78
invoke-static/range {p1 .. p1}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarms;->makeOutDatedAlarmAlert(Landroid/content/Context;)V

.line 79
invoke-static/range {p1 .. p1}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarms;->disableExpiredAlarms(Landroid/content/Context;)V

.line 80
invoke-static/range {p1 .. p1}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarms;->setNextAlert(Landroid/content/Context;)V

goto :goto_0

.line 83
:cond_3
const-string v3, "com.sonyericsson.alarm.ALARM_ALERT"

invoke-virtual/range {p2 .. p2}, Landroid/content/Intent;->getAction()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v4

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Ljava/lang/String;->equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

move-result v3

if-eqz v3, :cond_0

.line 88
const/4 v12, 0x0

.line 93
.local v12, "alarm":Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;
const-string v3, "intent.extra.alarm_raw"

move-object/from16 v0, p2

invoke-virtual {v0, v3}, Landroid/content/Intent;->getByteArrayExtra(Ljava/lang/String;)[B

move-result-object v16

.line 94
.local v16, "data":[B
if-eqz v16, :cond_4

.line 95
invoke-static {}, Landroid/os/Parcel;->obtain()Landroid/os/Parcel;

move-result-object v19

.line 96
.local v19, "in":Landroid/os/Parcel;
const/4 v3, 0x0

move-object/from16 v0, v16

array-length v4, v0

move-object/from16 v0, v19

move-object/from16 v1, v16

invoke-virtual {v0, v1, v3, v4}, Landroid/os/Parcel;->unmarshall([BII)V

.line 97
const/4 v3, 0x0

move-object/from16 v0, v19

invoke-virtual {v0, v3}, Landroid/os/Parcel;->setDataPosition(I)V

.line 98
sget-object v3, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->CREATOR:Landroid/os/Parcelable$Creator;

move-object/from16 v0, v19

invoke-interface {v3, v0}, Landroid/os/Parcelable$Creator;->createFromParcel(Landroid/os/Parcel;)Ljava/lang/Object;

move-result-object v12

.end local v12    # "alarm":Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;
check-cast v12, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;

.line 99
.restart local v12    # "alarm":Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;
invoke-virtual/range {v19 .. v19}, Landroid/os/Parcel;->recycle()V

.line 102
.end local v19    # "in":Landroid/os/Parcel;
:cond_4
if-nez v12, :cond_5

.line 103
const-string v3, "Failed to parse the alarm from the intent"

invoke-static {v3}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Log;->wtf(Ljava/lang/String;)V

.line 105
invoke-static/range {p1 .. p1}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarms;->setNextAlert(Landroid/content/Context;)V

goto/16 :goto_0

.line 110
:cond_5
iget v3, v12, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->id:I

move-object/from16 v0, p1

invoke-static {v0, v3}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarms;->disableSnoozeAlert(Landroid/content/Context;I)V

.line 112
iget-object v3, v12, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->daysOfWeek:Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm$DaysOfWeek;

invoke-virtual {v3}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm$DaysOfWeek;->isRepeatSet()Z

move-result v3

if-nez v3, :cond_6

.line 113
iget v3, v12, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->id:I

const/4 v4, 0x0

move-object/from16 v0, p1

invoke-static {v0, v3, v4}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarms;->enableAlarm(Landroid/content/Context;IZ)V

.line 122
:goto_1
invoke-static {}, Ljava/lang/System;->currentTimeMillis()J

move-result-wide v23

.line 123
.local v23, "now":J
new-instance v3, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

invoke-direct {v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V

const-string v4, "Recevied alarm set for "

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v3

iget-wide v6, v12, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->time:J

invoke-static {v6, v7}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Log;->formatTime(J)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v4

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v3

invoke-virtual {v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v3

invoke-static {v3}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Log;->v(Ljava/lang/String;)V

.line 126
iget-wide v3, v12, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->time:J

const-wide/32 v6, 0x1b7740

add-long/2addr v3, v6

cmp-long v3, v23, v3

if-lez v3, :cond_7

.line 127
const-string v3, "Ignoring stale alarm"

invoke-static {v3}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Log;->v(Ljava/lang/String;)V

goto/16 :goto_0

.line 117
.end local v23    # "now":J
:cond_6
invoke-static/range {p1 .. p1}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarms;->setNextAlert(Landroid/content/Context;)V

goto :goto_1

.line 133
.restart local v23    # "now":J
:cond_7
invoke-static/range {p1 .. p1}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/AlarmAlertWakeLock;->acquireCpuWakeLock(Landroid/content/Context;)V

.line 136
new-instance v15, Landroid/content/Intent;

const-string v3, "android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS"

invoke-direct {v15, v3}, Landroid/content/Intent;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

.line 137
.local v15, "closeDialogs":Landroid/content/Intent;
move-object/from16 v0, p1

invoke-virtual {v0, v15}, Landroid/content/Context;->sendBroadcast(Landroid/content/Intent;)V

.line 141
const-class v14, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/AlarmAlertFullScreen;

.line 144
.local v14, "c":Ljava/lang/Class;
new-instance v27, Landroid/content/Intent;

const-string v3, "com.sonyericsson.alarm.ALARM_ALERT"

move-object/from16 v0, v27

invoke-direct {v0, v3}, Landroid/content/Intent;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

.line 145
.local v27, "playAlarm":Landroid/content/Intent;
const-string v3, "intent.extra.alarm"

move-object/from16 v0, v27

invoke-virtual {v0, v3, v12}, Landroid/content/Intent;->putExtra(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/Parcelable;)Landroid/content/Intent;

.line 146
sget-object v3, Landroid/os/UserHandle;->CURRENT:Landroid/os/UserHandle;

move-object/from16 v0, p1

move-object/from16 v1, v27

invoke-virtual {v0, v1, v3}, Landroid/content/Context;->startService(Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)Landroid/content/ComponentName;

.line 151
new-instance v5, Landroid/content/Intent;

const-class v3, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/AlarmAlertFullScreen;

move-object/from16 v0, p1

invoke-direct {v5, v0, v3}, Landroid/content/Intent;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/Class;)V

.line 152
.local v5, "notify":Landroid/content/Intent;
const-string v3, "intent.extra.alarm"

invoke-virtual {v5, v3, v12}, Landroid/content/Intent;->putExtra(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/Parcelable;)Landroid/content/Intent;

.line 153
iget v4, v12, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->id:I

const/high16 v6, 0x8000000

const/4 v7, 0x0

sget-object v8, Landroid/os/UserHandle;->CURRENT:Landroid/os/UserHandle;

move-object/from16 v3, p1

invoke-static/range {v3 .. v8}, Landroid/app/PendingIntent;->getActivityAsUser(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/content/Intent;ILandroid/os/Bundle;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)Landroid/app/PendingIntent;

move-result-object v26

.line 158
.local v26, "pendingNotify":Landroid/app/PendingIntent;
move-object/from16 v0, p1

invoke-virtual {v12, v0}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->getLabelOrDefault(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v20

.line 159
.local v20, "label":Ljava/lang/String;
new-instance v13, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-object/from16 v0, p1

invoke-direct {v13, v0}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V

.line 160
.local v13, "builder":Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;
const v3, 0x7f020050

invoke-virtual {v13, v3}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setSmallIcon(I)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v3

move-object/from16 v0, v20

invoke-virtual {v3, v0}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setTicker(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v3

iget-wide v6, v12, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->time:J

invoke-virtual {v3, v6, v7}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setWhen(J)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v3

move-object/from16 v0, v20

invoke-virtual {v3, v0}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setContentTitle(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v3

const v4, 0x7f0b0019

move-object/from16 v0, p1

invoke-virtual {v0, v4}, Landroid/content/Context;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v4

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setContentText(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v3

move-object/from16 v0, v26

invoke-virtual {v3, v0}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setContentIntent(Landroid/app/PendingIntent;)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v3

const/4 v4, 0x1

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setOngoing(Z)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

move-result-object v3

const/4 v4, 0x1

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setLocalOnly(Z)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

.line 167
const-string v3, "phone"

move-object/from16 v0, p1

invoke-virtual {v0, v3}, Landroid/content/Context;->getSystemService(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

move-result-object v28

check-cast v28, Landroid/telephony/TelephonyManager;

.line 169
.local v28, "telephonyManager":Landroid/telephony/TelephonyManager;
invoke-virtual/range {v28 .. v28}, Landroid/telephony/TelephonyManager;->getCallState()I

move-result v3

if-nez v3, :cond_8

.line 170
new-instance v8, Landroid/content/Intent;

move-object/from16 v0, p1

invoke-direct {v8, v0, v14}, Landroid/content/Intent;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/Class;)V

.line 171
.local v8, "alarmAlert":Landroid/content/Intent;
const-string v3, "intent.extra.alarm"

invoke-virtual {v8, v3, v12}, Landroid/content/Intent;->putExtra(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/Parcelable;)Landroid/content/Intent;

.line 172
const/high16 v3, 0x10040000

invoke-virtual {v8, v3}, Landroid/content/Intent;->setFlags(I)Landroid/content/Intent;

.line 175
iget v7, v12, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->id:I

const/high16 v9, 0x8000000

const/4 v10, 0x0

sget-object v11, Landroid/os/UserHandle;->CURRENT:Landroid/os/UserHandle;

move-object/from16 v6, p1

invoke-static/range {v6 .. v11}, Landroid/app/PendingIntent;->getActivityAsUser(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/content/Intent;ILandroid/os/Bundle;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)Landroid/app/PendingIntent;

move-result-object v18

.line 178
.local v18, "fullScreenIntent":Landroid/app/PendingIntent;
const/4 v3, 0x1

move-object/from16 v0, v18

invoke-virtual {v13, v0, v3}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->setFullScreenIntent(Landroid/app/PendingIntent;Z)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;

.line 180
.end local v8    # "alarmAlert":Landroid/content/Intent;
.end local v18    # "fullScreenIntent":Landroid/app/PendingIntent;
:cond_8
invoke-virtual {v13}, Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;->build()Landroid/app/Notification;

move-result-object v21

.line 184
.local v21, "n":Landroid/app/Notification;
invoke-direct/range {p0 .. p1}, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/AlarmReceiver;->getNotificationManager(Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/app/NotificationManager;

move-result-object v22

.line 185
.local v22, "nm":Landroid/app/NotificationManager;
const/4 v3, 0x0

iget v4, v12, Lcom/sonyericsson/alarm/Alarm;->id:I

sget-object v6, Landroid/os/UserHandle;->CURRENT:Landroid/os/UserHandle;

move-object/from16 v0, v22

move-object/from16 v1, v21

invoke-virtual {v0, v3, v4, v1, v6}, Landroid/app/NotificationManager;->notifyAsUser(Ljava/lang/String;ILandroid/app/Notification;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)V

goto/16 :goto_0
.end method
```

Hope i can port it!!thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look:

You have this error: 09-08 00:37:00.130 E/AndroidRuntime(21010): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

According to the documentation that means:

Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.

Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

Link to the documentation:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah i know that method is startService..but i need help with the smali file:-(